# Query which inserts then Updates SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Is it possible to have an insert statement and once that is complete straight away run an update statement?

So Here are my statements:

**Insert**

```
truncate table table1;
INSERT INTO table2 (name,value, ATY)
SELECT table1.name,table1.Value,table1.ATY
FROM table1;
```

As soon as that is complete, I need the following update to run:

**Update**

```
update table2
   SET value=TRIM( BOTH '+' FROM REPLACE( '+' || value || '+', '++', '+000+' ) )
```

Is this possible?

Comment: `INSERT INTO table2 (name,value, ATY) select table1.name, TRIM( BOTH '+' FROM REPLACE( '+' || table1.Value|| '+', '++', '+000+' ) ), table1.ATY
FROM table1;`

Comment: @jarlh.. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do both in one statement?

```
truncate table table2;

INSERT INTO table2 (name, value, ATY)
    SELECT t1.name,
           TRIM( BOTH '+' FROM REPLACE( '+' || t1.value || '+', '++', '+000+' ) ),
           t1.ATY
    FROM table1 t1;
```

Note:  I assume that you intend to truncate `table2`, not `table1`.  If you truncate `table1`, then the `insert` will not do anything because the table will be empty.

Comment: yes correct it should have been table 2 that is being truncated. I was originally trying this but got a constraint error for some reason. But your answer works
Thank you